# Difference in browser behavior when clicking a link vs. copy-pasting it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, browser, load

I'm curious what sort of difference there is in browser behavior when loading a page by clicking through a link vs. copy-pasting said link into the browser bar. Is there a general difference in the load process that I should know about?

I ask because I am working on an application using the Google Maps API, in which the user is able to create custom map links with a GPS location defined in the URL. The links work fine when copy-pasted into the browser; however, if the link is clicked directly, the browser generates a 'stack exceeded' exception (appropriate for this site!).

While I understand that generally we like to see code examples on Stack Overflow, I'm going to refrain from that for now - perhaps if anyone knows about differences in the  DOM loading process between click and copy-paste, I can use that to narrow in on the issue without bogging down the discussion with tangentially-related code.

The same issue occurs in both Firefox and Chrome.

thanks!

Comment: You are tackling the issue the wrong way. Instead of asking for a list of all things that are different between the two, wouldn't it be wiser to ask about how to fix your specific problem? Who *exactly* gives you the "stack exceeded" message - two different browsers? That sounds really unlikely. Does it happen on different machines in the same way? I'd say it seems more likely it's a server side issue, which is a whole new field to look at.

Comment: "Maximum call stack size exceeded" - Chrome, "too much recursion" - Firefox, both referencing "main.js" - seems likely to be stemming from the same issue

Comment: You're very right though, I need to look more closely at what the specific error is on each browser

Comment: It seems to be an question of how the browser is encoding the link - in Firefox, (although not Chrome) the tildes (~) in the URL are replaced with %7E, which throws off the JS that is decoding the URL. Chrome doesn't show any replacement, but the link still freezes when clicked directly

Comment: Fair enough, you were right and it was a client side thing after all. Wow, wouldn't have thought that to be possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copying and pasting the link, try right clicking and copying the link address.  Basically, the links on a web page can display differently than they are.

Comment: Good call - when doing so I noticed that in Firefox, clicking the link replaces the tildes (~) with %7E, which throws off the script. I thought since ~s were legal characters in a URL, it would be ok.. I may need to use another character to separate sections of the data encoded in the URL

Comment: A fun thing to do is do a normal search on google, and hover over the links... you'll see the link on the bottom left (in Chrome) as the normal link.  However, they have an onclick that replaces it with the google representation of the link.  One way to look at this is to just right click on the link, and that executes the change.  When you hover over it again, it will display the "googled" version :)